# breaking url apart from input with javascript and fill values in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Its been a while for me with JavaScript (jQuery?). But I'm looking for a sensible way of breaking a link from input and putting vars into form, without reloading page. My plan was to input values on fly when link is pasted.

My url is : http://www.domain.com/value_value-gxxxxxx-dxxxxxx-value-varable_varable_value.html

What I'm looking for to achieve is remove domain from link and input value_value-gxxxxxx-dxxxxxxxx-value-varable_varable_value.html into form one and after I need to grab dxxxxxxxx (I need only xxxxxxx - length my vary.

I'm really ripping my hair out, don't even know what to start with ....

Comment: I would suggest looking at regular expressions.

Comment: hi. maybe got some link to working sample? turned google upside down

Comment: `String.split()` would probably play into it, too.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail the convention you plan to use to identify the field names and values?  You could just pass them in query string format e.g. `domain.com?name=value&name2=value2` - you can find parsers for those that others have written pretty easily.

Comment: Can you post closer to real example? I think it can be done with some splits pretty easily.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions and http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html are two good places to start.

Comment: So plan is that person come to page with link in its clipboard and paste it into input field. what I like script to do is to brake link apart into two different input fields in values I need. one with removed domain after slash. other is to grab value starting with d (dxxxxx). Gxxxxx and dxxxxxx are variables and will be different on each link so I dont actually got any anchors. easy to do with php, but I cant afford to reload page. In link there are no anchors at all ($%&#).